# MySQL console: change user host in conncetion string

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to connect to the MySQL database using MySQL console.

MySQL has user: test@% without password.

When i'm trying to connect:

> mysql -u test -h 127.0.0.1

I got error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

How i can change user 'test'@'localhost' to 'test@%'?

Comment: Just leva away the host flag: `mysql -u test`. But anyway, that is _not_ your problem here.

Comment: Bad idea, because it still uses @localhost but with default user.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a bit strange logic about the placeholder host, i.e. permissions for the host `%`. (I'm not sure if "placeholder host" is the correct official name for this.) Namely, the placeholder host does **not** capture `localhost`. This can be a bit counter-intuitive.

To be able to log in you will therefore either have to connect from a remote IP (i.e. another computer) or have to grant permissions to `test@localhost`.

Comment: I'm using ssh tunnel, so it is not a variant.

Comment: Well, then you'll have to go with the second option I suggested.